# Naive Bayes model (.pkl) take too much time to predict

Tags: python, flask, pickle, wsgi, naivebayes

I am using naive bayes algorithm for predict sentiment of the sentence. I am creating a model for future use. I am using cpickle to save the model. But when I load and predict the sentence, it takes too much time. It take too much time to load .pkl file which is about 100MB. There is 3 models. I am using Flask micro service in python. So for every request each model(.pkl) is load and give the output. It takes about 30-45 sec per request.

```
def predict(sentence):
  test = cPickle.load(open('model.pkl'))
  print test.predict([sentence])[0]
  print max(test.predict_proba([sentence])[0])
```

I also tried to load the model before request, but wsgi server start every time a new Flask instance and it load the model into memory. So it takes too much memory.

My question is
Is there any way that I can save the model in Redis/ any Db
Or How I can reduce the loading time of cpickel file.??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's best to retain the model in memory to service requests quickly.

It is a necessary evil in your case, because like you said that the only other approach otherwise is to read the model everytime a new request comes, in which case your server will be overloaded pretty quickly.

Like you are suggesting, it would actually be a good idea to save the models in redis, which is an in-memory solution.